# Degree sequence of trees

Tags: graph-theory

Give an algorithm to determine whether a tree can be constructed from the given degree sequence.Construct the tree on the sequence 3,2,1,1,1

Comment: a) what have you tried? b) Do you mean graph, not tree? c) there is no tree with degree sequence [3, 3, 2, 1, 1] as the degree sum is 10 yet the number of vertices is 5 and for trees V = E - 1

Comment: I thought about adding the degree sequences and checking whether it equals 2*(n-1). If it doesnt follow the  rule, we can directly say that the sequence doesnt form a tree

Comment: I want an algorithm for the sufficient part

Comment: Given and constructed. Now what?

Comment: I want you to give me a generalised algorithm  that can answer the question. The sequence I give can be just be used as an example

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/14100/condition-on-degrees-for-existence-of-a-tree?rq=1

Comment: That is a necessary condition , I want the sufficient part

Comment: @user3600483: The argument for sufficiency is actually sketched in the accepted answer, and that argument easily yields an algorithm. I’ve described it (rather informally) in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that the degree sequence is $d_1,d_2,\ldots,d_n$, where as usual $d_1\ge d_2\ge\ldots\ge d_n$, and suppose that $\sum_{k=1}^nd_k=2(n-1)$. If $d_n=0$, then $n=1$ and we have the unique tree on one vertex, so I will assume that $d_n\ge 1$. It follows that $2(n-1)=\sum_{k=1}^nd_k\ge n$ and hence that $n\ge 2$. Clearly $d_n=1$. For $k=1,\ldots,d_1$ let $n_k$ be the number of vertices with degree $k$.

Let $\ell=\min\{k>1:n_k\ne 0\}$. If $\ell>n_1+1$, then

$$2(n-1)-n_1=\sum_{k=2}^nkd_k=\sum_{k=\ell}^nkd_k\ge(n-n_1)(n_1+2)\;,$$

so

$$n_1^2+(1-n)n_1-2\ge 0\;,$$

and hence

$$n_1\ge\frac{n-1+\sqrt{(n-1)^2+8}}2=\frac{n-1}2+\sqrt{\left(\frac{n-1}2\right)^2+2}>n-1\;.$$

But then $n_1=n$, so $2(n-1)=n$, and $n=2$: this is the unique tree with two vertices and one edge. Thus, we may as well assume that $\ell\le n_1+1$.

Remove the $d_1$ $1$s from the degree sequence; $d_{n-n_1}=\ell$ is the smallest remaining degree. As long as $d_{n-n_1}>1$, subtract $1$ from it and from $n_1$; $d_{n-n_1}$ will reach $1$ in at most $\ell-1$ steps, and $\ell-1\le n_1$, so $n_1$ will still be non-negative when $d_{n-n_1}$ reaches $1$. If $n_1$ is still positive, move back to $d_{n-n_1-1}$ and decrement it and $n_1$ in parallel until either it reaches $1$ or $n_1$ reaches $0$, whichever comes first. If it reaches $1$ first, move back to $d_{n-n_1-2}$ and repeat. Eventually $n_1$ reaches $0$, and I leave to you to check that you now have a degree sequence $d_1',\ldots,d_{n-n_1}'$ of length $n-n_1$ such that $\sum_{k=1}^{n-n_1}d_k'=2(n-n_1-1)$.

Suppose that we know how to build a tree $T'$ with this shorter degree sequence. We can get a tree $T$ for the original degree sequence by adding $n_1$ leaves: specifically, for $k=1,\ldots,n-n_1$ we add $d_k-d_k'$ leaves to vertex $k$.

Now employ this construction recursively.

> **Example:** Suppose that we’re given the degree sequence $4,3,3,3,3,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1$; here $n=14$ and $n_1=8$. After we apply the above reduction procedure, we end up with the degree sequence $4,2,1,1,1,1$: we decrement the original $2$ once, each of the last three $3$s twice, and the first $3$ once.
>
> Now apply the reduction procedure to $4,2,1,1,1,1$; the result is the degree sequence $1,1$, resulting from decrementing the $2$ once and the $4$ three times. At this point we evidently have the tree
>
> ```
>           *-------------------*
> ```
>
> If the lefthand vertex is the one corresponding to $4$ in the degree sequence $4,2,1,1,1,1$, it will receive $4-1=3$ leaves when we work back to get a tree for the sequence $4,2,1,1,1,1$. The other vertex will correspond to $2$ in that degree sequence, and it will get the fourth leaf:
>
> ```
>           *-------------------*  
>          /|\                  |  
>         * * *                 *
> ```
>
> The six vertices of this tree correspond to the first six members of the original degree sequence, i.e., to $4,3,3,3,3,2$. The last five of these degrees were decremented when we reduced the original sequence to $4,2,1,1,1,1$. The vertex of degree $4$ at the upper left therefore requires no further modification; the vertex of degree $2$ at the upper right needs to acquire one leaf; three of the leaves need to grow two leaves each (to boost their degrees up to $3$); and the remaining leaf needs to grow just one leaf. This last step can evidently be carried out in more than one way, since we can choose any of the four leaves to be the one that grows a single leaf, but it’s clear that we can add $8$ leaves to get a tree with the desired degree sequence.