# How many trees with $n$ vertices correspond to the vector $(g_1,g_2,g_3,g_4)$, where the $g_i$ are the number of vertices of degree $i$?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, trees, planar-graphs

Let there be a tree with $n$ vertices. How to count the number of trees corresponding to the set $(g_1,g_2,g_3,g_4)$, where $g_i$ is the number of vertices of degree $i$? For example, with $n=8$ we have the sequences $(2,6,0,0)$, $(3,4,1,0)$, etc. Is there a general way to count trees corresponding to the set $(g_1,g_2,g_3,g_4)$?

Comment: Are the trees labelled? If so, then you can use Prüfer codes (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pr%C3%BCfer_sequence#Other_applications[4]) and get the value $\frac{n!}{g_1!g_2!g_3!g_4!} \frac{(n-2)!}{(2!)^{g_3}(3!)^{g_4}}$

Comment: Except if that sequence of $g$'s isn't possible, then it doesn't give zero. I think you can use this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1932853/degree-sequence-of-trees to determine whether a degree sequence is possible for a tree.

Comment: Hello, ploosu2! Trees are not marked. Here's an example for you: with n=6 we have the sequences (2,4,0,0) - it corresponds to one tree, (3,2,1,0) - two trees, (4,0,2,0) - one tree and (4,1,0,1) - one tree. Thus, for n=6 we have 5 trees.

Comment: Ok, then it might be harder.